# What are these metal guide tools?

Tags: tools

I recently came into the possession of these 3 metal things. Can anyone tell me what these are and what they are used for?
Each have 3 holes in the bottom. One has a large round cutout in the top the with 1"-25MM on it. [image: piece 1]

The next one has two smaller round cutouts in the top with 3/4"-19MM 5/8"-16MM under the cutout.[image: piece 2]

The Last one has a large v-shaped cut out with a 90º next to the cutout. [image: Piece 3]

Comment: They look like interchangeable jaws of a crimping tool such as for pex fittings except for the 90degree one. Are there any other parts  that you found with these?

Comment: No there aren't any other parts. I got them at a Habitat for Humanity store and they were just sitting by themselves, the workers there didn't know what they were either.

Comment: I would agree with @AlaskaMan - removable jaws for some kind of crimper. Based on the holes - they all fit the same handle set. That 90° is puzzling...

Comment: I would also agree someone had a nice set at one time.

Comment: maybe not from a crimper, but from a cuter